# Why is the "./" (dot + forward slash) needed in Ruby files when using the require keyword?

Tags: ruby, irb

When attempting to place Ruby dependency files into a Ruby file, why is the "./" (dot + forward slash) necessary when typing out the file directory? Oddly enough it is only needed when using the `require` keyword and not the `load` keyword.

i.e.:
module.rb (the dependency)

```
module SomeModule
    def someMethod
      puts "hello"
    end
end
```

method.rb

```
require "./module.rb" 
#require "module.rb" does not work

class Animal
 include SomeModule
end

class Person
    include SomeModule
end

animal = Animal.new
animal.someMethod

person = Person.new
person.someMethod

#irb --> need to also write require " ./method.rb" to call it
```

Comment: Does module.rb have a shebang line?

Comment: Not sure what a shebang line is, but I've put in the content of module.rb

Comment: This has nothing to do with windows. It's the same in other OSes too.

Comment: That could be true... I've seen a tutorial though, and the instructor had a Mac and did not need the "./". That's really besides the point though, wondering what the "./" stands for and why it's necessary for `require` and not `load`.

Comment: If the instructor did not need the `./` to load a file from the current directory using `require`, then they were using an older version of Ruby.

Comment: @philomory: huh? How older? LOAD_PATH doesn't include current dir since... always.

Comment: If by 'since always' you mean '[since Ruby 1.9.2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/18/ruby-1-9.2-released/)', then yes ;)

Comment: @philomory: that's exactly what I meant :)

Comment: To be fair to @SergioTulentsev anything pre-1.9.3 is pretty damn old. ;)

Comment: Yeah ok that makes sense considering the video was released in 2009 :) .

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I will take your word that you need to do the same thing on other OSes, and change the title of question so it includes all OSes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is only needed when using the require keyword and not the load
>   keyword. Why?

`load`, `require` and `require_relative` are all methods which take a filename as an argument that is to be loaded. They need to locate the filename passed an an argument

> **load**

**load** checks for the file in the **LOAD PATH** which can be accessed using the global variable `$LOAD_PATH` or `$:` Even though the *current working directory* (designated by **.**) is NOT actually in the LOAD_PATH, the **load** method *acts* as if it is so is able to locate a file without explicitly appending the current directory to the file name passed as an argument

> **require**

**require** is similar to **load** with two main differences

The first is that it's unaware about the *current working directory*. It does not *add* it to the LOAD PATH so once ruby searches it, it doesn't find the file. This is why you have to explicitly tell ruby about the *current working directory* and how to locate the file from the current directory using **./path_to_file**.

If you don't want to add **./**, you have to add the current directory to your Load Path

```
$: << '.'
require 'module.rb'
```

This will work as the current directory is now in the load path which is where ruby will search for the file.

The second main difference is that when you make multiple calls to **require** in a file passing it the same filename as an argument, the file will be *required* only the first time. Ruby keeps track of the files *required*. However with multiple calls to **load** with the same filename as an argument, the file is always *loaded*.

```
require 'time' => true
require 'time' => false #second call within the same file
```

> **require_relative**

**require_relative** searches *relative to the file* in which the method call was executed which is why you don't need to alter the LOAD PATH by explicitly adding the *current working directory*

Comment: That's not quite accurate. `.` is the current working directory of the _process_. `require_relative` is the directory that contains the current _file_. There can be a _big_ difference there. In general, I only ever use `require` for gems/libraries, and use `require_relative` for all of my project's own files (when I'm not just using the `require_all` gem).

Comment: Yes `.` is the current working directory, `require_relative` is NOT the directory that contains the current file. It is able to search for the file _relative to the current working directory_  because it is aware of it. Personally I agree that it's best to use `require_relative`, I just explained how `require` could be used to achieve the same thing by being aware of the current directory

Comment: No, `require_relative` does *not* search relative to the current working directory, it searches relative to the current *file* (that's why it doesn't work in IRb: there is no current file).

Comment: You're absolutely right,  It searches the _directory relative to the file in which the method call was executed_. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit my answer for a clearer and thorough explanation

Answer (score 1):

If module.rb and method.rb are in the same directory, instead of using `require` you should use `require_relative`. Thus, the top of method.rb would look like this

```
require_relative 'module'

class Animal
```

Comment: Do you know what the ./ does though?

Comment: @the12: don't you? The dot is reference to current dir. And slash is just a file path separator.

Comment: In windows as well as other OSes, a bare `.` represents the current directory, so `./module.rb` means "the 'module.rb' file in the current directory" in the same way that `C:/module.rb` would mean "the file 'module.rb' at the root of the C: drive"

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that `.` represents the current directory _of the running ruby process_, not the directory of the file it's written in. That's why `require_relative` is a better solution - it explicitly looks relative to the current file, rather than relative to whichever folder you were in when you invoked the `ruby` command

Comment: Read the docs: "Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the feature is already loaded. If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be searched for in the directories listed in $LOAD_PATH ($:)."

So, `require` needs the `.` because the file you are trying to require is not in the $LOAD_PATH

http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require

Comment: @philomory Ok that makes sense....  I guess the current running ruby process of IRB is different than my current directory... If you just copy & paste that answer (including require_relative and C:/ explanation)  in, I will pick it as the accepted answer.

Comment: And the reason `require` uses the LOAD_PATH is so that it can find things like gems and the standard library, not just stuff in the current directory. Otherwise, you'd need to do `requre C:\ruby\2.0.0\gems\whatever.rb`, which would be pretty terrible.

Comment: @the12 There are several people involved in this comment thread; I didn't write the answer :-p

Comment: @Brennan: well, docs for `load` say the same thing, but it works.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I thought the docs differed, but I was mistaken. This has been a bug for a while: https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/2710